# Strange query performance of SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I noticed some performance problems with my DB.  Such query (just for a example):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ActionHistory 
 WHERE ObjectId = @id"
```

...executes at random with different reads and duration.  ObjectId is Foreign Key, with index on it.

With SQL Profiler I found, that sometimes the results are: 5 reads, 0 duration, but in another case: 5 reads, 200 duration. Such big durations occurs accidentally.

I use distributed transaction with WCF. Such results I got when I was the only user at that time, so it likely not to be a locks or something else.

What is the reason of such behaviour: low reads, but high query duration ?

Comment: Firstly, record XML query plans using SQL profiler and compare them

Answer (score 1):

In general, distributed transactions are extremely expensive.  Try disabling distributed transactions in your environment to see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since the query is exactly the same each time and the reads are the same, then it's most likely due to locking.  Sometimes another query is executing and may have a lock on the records that need to be accessed.  Waiting for the lock to be released would cause a slowdown.

Using SQL Profiler to compare start/stop times for queries you can identify overlapping queries that may cause locking.

This is not an indication of a problem, just an explanation of the differences you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Enable read committed snapshot in the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE ... SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

This will miraculously change your reads that occur under the default read-committed isolation into snapshot reads, which are not hindered by locks. See [Choosing Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277.aspx) for details, including the runtime resource usage caused by enabling snapshot reads.